Flashing previous screen after navigation
I have a page with GoogleMap and other widgets like a Custom AppBar and BottomSheet etc. There are few buttons for navigating to preferences screens,
If I navigated to one of the preferences(Screen A) screen from the MapScreen(Screen M) and navigated back to the MapScreen(Screen M), I'm getting a flashing (for a fraction of a second) of the preferences screen(Screen A) After I navigated to any other screen(Screen X) after that.
All navigations mentioned above are Navigator.pushNamed. I guess pages dispose after Pop

Can you provide some code? It's really hard to visualize the problem just with what you provided, try providing a minimum viable solution!

I fixed it by wrapping the GoogleMap widget by Visibility Widget and hiding it right after navigating to other screens

Not sure why this happens though I fixed it by wrapping the GoogleMap widget or the widget class that contains the GoogleMap with a Visibility Widget and hiding it right after navigating to any other page.
Navigator.pushNamed(context, AnyOtherPage.routeName);
visibilityNotifier.value=false;// used valuNotifier for rebuilding the widget

